# Unable to mount nfs share using autofs on solaris10

Tags: nfs, solaris-10, automount

I am trying to mount an nfs share to a solaris 10 machine at bootup without any luck so far.

The nfs share is accessible and mounts without any problems if I do so manually from the command line (mount -F nfs server_hostname:/exported_dir_path/ /mnt/tmpdir). But I don't know how to tell autofs to mount it at bootup.

We have another machine on the same network (also solaris) that has it working, but I can't figure out how is it configured differently from the non-working one.

I googled the problem and found that /etc/vfstab, /etc/auto_master, and /etc/hosts files need to have proper entries to make this work. I compared these files from the non-working machine with the ones on working machine but did not notice any differences.

Could someone please guide me to properly configure autofs to mount nfs shares on a solaris10 machine?

Thanks,

Aashish.

Comment: `autofs` won't mount the file system until something tries to access it.  If you want the filesystem to be mounted on boot even if it's not accessed, you have to either access it to force the automounter to actually mount the filesystem, or mount it with something other than `autofs`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : I think I missed out some information here. I expect the shares to be visible under /net directory. On the working machine there are directories for each nfs share under /net (e.g. /net/server1/object_files , /net/server2/prebuilt_libs) and I can cd to them. Also, from your response, how can I try to access the path that isn't even visible? what am I missing here.

Comment: OK.  I read your question as if you were asking why the filesystem wasn't mounted at boot, not that you're having problems accessing them via `/net/...` mountpoints.  On your system that's having problems, can you access the filesystems via IP address:  `/net/192.168.1.1/...`?  (Use the actual IP address of the server)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, that does not work for me. Sorry for not mentioning /net/xxx mount points earlier, as I thought it was not that much different from a regular nfs share.